# Event listener that will pull data from a selected column in a ListView PS

Tags: wpf, powershell, scripting

As title says, I need help to create an event listener. I've searched for other answers, but they don't really help me, and I'm new to programming so I am struggling with this.

The purpose of the script is to search for scripts on the local system, pull information about them, and then display it on a GUI interface. From the interface, you would select the different displayed scripts, and be able to run the selected script, get script notes from the corresponding text file for the script, and also open the file path in file explorer.

The first section of my code is this:

```
Add-Type –assemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type –assemblyName PresentationCore
Add-Type –assemblyName WindowsBase

[Xml]$xaml = (design code omitted)

$xmlNodeReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader($xaml)
$Window = [System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($xmlNodeReader)
```

This is the base for the rest of my stuff, which I haven't been able to find much help with. The next section of code is the header to prepare to fill the columns.

```
$values = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\(Directory) -Filter *.ps1 -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
$ListView = $Window.FindName("OutputList")

# outputlist is the name of the listview in the xaml #
(further down would be the foreach loop to create the columns and register the data)

$ListView.ItemsSource = $values
```

Past that, I have nothing. I can't figure out how to create the listener for the selected item on the ListView. If I can do that, I should be able to grab the data and be set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From other questions, WPF listview has a `SelectionChanged` event, and from [FoxDeploy's WPF GUIs in PowerShell series, Part IV](https://foxdeploy.com/2015/09/08/powershell-guis-how-to-handle-events-and-create-a-tabbed-interface/), the way to add event listeners is like so:

```
$ListView.Add_SelectionChanged({

    # code here

})
```

Where the `{}` is a PowerShell scriptblock

Comment: Got it. Would you also happen to know how to pull data from a specific column? I saw it shown as this: `$ListView.SelectedItems[1].Text` , but I'm not sure if that is functional.

Comment: Technically speaking it gets cast to an `[action]`/`delegate`